# Can't add box-shadow to input elements

Tags: css

I don't seem to be able to add box shadows to input elements, my CSS is kind of like this http://jsfiddle.net/DLCTh/ and as you can see it applies correctly on div elements but not on text inputs, am I missing something? Or is it that I can't do this?

Comment: Which browser(s) are you testing with?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

add

```
border:0
```

or

```
border:none
```

http://jsfiddle.net/DLCTh/1/

Comment: Why can't you have a border and a box shadow?

Comment: It's not so much that you can't have a border and a box-shadow, it's that without setting the border value the browser will often use it's own button style.

Answer (score 1):

It's because of the border on the input. Add border: none; and it should work.